# Updating The Email Change Verification URL

Tags: visualforce, community, email-template, merge-field

Am looking to update the verification link that is sent out when a user changes their email on our community (VF) storefront.

I have checked the email templates and see the merge field, but cannot figure out how to set the value of the email verification merge field {!ChgEmailVer.Url}

Is this possible to use another page?

Comment: The value is provided by Salesforce automatically. You don't need to provide it.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to edit the page? For example to customize the 'continue' link or any other text on it?

Comment: Actually we resolved this via 301 so all is good and it works now.